# Where can I find opennlp.tools.lang.dutch.* packages for Dutch tools?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I'm trying to use [TextRank](https://github.com/samxhuan/textrank) on Dutch text. The implementation of TextRank has [LanguageEnglish](https://github.com/samxhuan/textrank/blob/master/src/com/sharethis/textrank/LanguageEnglish.java) and [LanguageSpanish](https://github.com/samxhuan/textrank/blob/master/src/com/sharethis/textrank/LanguageSpanish.java) classes, and they import OpenNLP classes such as

```
import opennlp.tools.lang.english.ParserTagger;
import opennlp.tools.lang.english.SentenceDetector;
import opennlp.tools.lang.english.Tokenizer;
```

and

```
import opennlp.tools.lang.spanish.PosTagger;
import opennlp.tools.lang.spanish.SentenceDetector;
import opennlp.tools.lang.spanish.Tokenizer;
```

I want to extend TextRank for Dutch, and for this I've created a new LanguageDutch class but I couldn't find the corresponding OpenNLP classes to import, such as

```
opennlp.tools.lang.dutch.PosTagger;
opennlp.tools.lang.dutch.SentenceDetector; 
opennlp.tools.lang.dutch.Tokenizer;
```

where can I find them (or are there third-party implementations)?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the code I was dealing with used a very old version of OpenNLP. Switching to the latest version of [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/), and importing the more generic classes, [as shown here](https://github.com/emres/textrank/blob/master/src/com/sharethis/textrank/LanguageDutch.java), solved the problem.

Comment: Glad that worked.  The https://github.com/samxhuan/textrank repo came from code which I'd originally authored while at ShareThis, and I don't think they've updated it. There's a fork in my account at https://github.com/ceteri/textrank with some updates -- though I've switched over to Scale or Py instead for later implementations, if that helps https://github.com/ceteri/pytextrank/